# How to implement maximum array function in Java

Tags: javascript, java, arrays

Im trying to develop a similar function in **JAVA** but I don't quite understand what the -Infinity does in **JAVA** and how I can use it.

I show you the **JS** code:

```
function arrayMax(arr) {
 var len = arr.length, 
 max = -Infinity;
 var rangomax=99999;
 while (len--) {
  if ((Number(arr[len]) > max)&&(Number(arr[len])<rangomax)) {
   max = Number(arr[len]);
  }
 }
 return max;
}
```

Comment: The java equivalent would be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: @Bufank85 java is not remotely related to javascript. Remove this tag. -Infinity is displayed when a number exceeds the lower limit of the floating point numbers, which is -1.797693134862316E+308.

Comment: @azurefrog No, the Java equivalent is `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`. The JS `Number()` function coerces the array value to a `Double`. Nothing in the question says that the numbers are only integers, so we should assume that they can be same type of number as in JavaScript, i.e. `Double`.

Comment: @FailingCoder You seem to have entirely misunderstood the question. Question says *"trying to develop a **similar** function in JAVA"*. OP has that JavaScript code, and knows how it works, but is asking how to write similar code ***in Java***.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, I thought I had written wrong but it's perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Here try this:

```
public double arrayMax(double[] arr){
    int len = arr.length;
    double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    double rangomax = 99999;
    while(len--){
        if ((arr[len] > max) && (arr[len] < rangomax)) {
             max = arr[len];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Why are you assuming that `arr` is an `int[]`? If anything, we should assume that it is a `double[]`, since JavaScript only supports one numeric type, `double`, and the question doesn't specify that values are integers only. --- Technically, `arr` could be an `Object[]` and the repeated calls to `Number()` coerces the value to `double`.

Comment: int was assumed since the max range is 99999  which is under int.

Comment: `double` should be assumed, since the return value should be `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` if `arr` is empty. Since your code doesn't behave the same as the JavaScript code, I'm down-voting *(for now)*.

Comment: Updated with double

Answer (score 0):

For Java code that is as close to the JavaScript code as possible, ignoring `undefined` and `null` values, we should assume that input is an `Object[]`, otherwise there wouldn't have been a need for all the `Number()` calls.

```java
public static double arrayMax(Object... arr) {
    double rangomax = 99999;
    double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    for (Object obj : arr) {
        double value = number(obj);
        if (value > max && value < rangomax) {
            max = value;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
// Similar to JavaScript's Number() function
private static double number(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Number) {
        return ((Number) obj).doubleValue();
    }
    try {
        return Double.parseDouble(obj.toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
}
```

Of course, you might want overloads for primitive values, e.g.

```java
public static double arrayMax(double... arr) {
    double rangomax = 99999;
    double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    for (double value : arr) {
        if (value > max && value < rangomax) {
            max = value;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to find the maximum:

```
public Double maxOfArray(int[] arr) { 

    double max = Double.MIN_VALUE; 

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ 

        if (arr[i] > max) { 

            max = arr[i];

        } 

    } 

    return max; 

}
```

Answer (score -1):

As people before me noted you can use Integer.MIN_VALUE can do the trick.
You can get the same outcome with without Integer.MIN_VALUE

```
  public int max(int[] arr){
    if(arr == null || arr.length == 0) {
      return 0; // you can return any default value in case arr is empty or null
    }
    int max = arr[0];
    for(int num: arr){
      if(num >= max){
        max = num;
      }
    }
    return max;
  }
```

Edit: 
This would also work with double[]

Comment: *"you can return any default value"* Not if you want the code to behave the same as the JavaScript code, because then you only have one choice: `return Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;` --- That of course will fail to compile, given the declared return type. --- Sorry, solution that behaves differently deserves a down-vote from me (for now).

Comment: @Andreas 
This is exacly what the comment is for, as I know this is not the exact behaviour I have added this comment so it will be known :)

Comment: Since OP is specifically asking for the Java equivalent to `-Infinity`, you should at least show what that is as the "default" return value, i.e. answer the question. It is certainly not `0`.

Comment: @Andreas I assumed OP wanted a similar function not the equivalent of -infinity since the title of his post is "How to implement maximum array function in Java" so I gave an alterntaive.

Comment: @Andreas I see you feel very stongly about this so its time for me to leave.
I was trying to help, hope this kind of reactions will not discourage others from doing so :)

Comment: And I was only trying to help you improve the answer, but it doesn't seem like you want help with that, so I'll leave the down-vote in place, since the answer is still not answering the question, and the code is still not producing the same results as the JavaScript code.